# Converting several strings into one byte[]

Tags: c#, string, encoding, byte

I have to retrieve a number of Unicode strings from SOAP calls and SQL Server calls. Then, I have to convert everything to a byte[] in UTF7 so it can be sent through a socket to a server expecting a UTF7 string of bytes.  Since I have to insert control bytes after each string, I can't just concatenate the strings and use one Encoding call. (simplified code example):

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF7;
byte[] bytes = new byte[16384];
int idx = 0;
bytes[idx++] = 11; // Starting control code

// create an array of strings from different sources.
string[] strs = GetTheStrings();

foreach (string str in strs)
{
   bytes[idx] = enc.GetBytes(str); // Error

   idx += enc.GetByteCount(str);
   bytes[idx++] = 13;  // line ending CR


}
bytes[idx] = 28; // ending control code

return bytes;
```

I get an error from VS saying that enc.GetBytes(str); "Cannot explicitly convert type byte[] to byte & adds something about needing to override the Encoding class. Why does VS treat bytes[idx] differently than, say, byte[] bytes2 - which works on a string by string basis? I'm used to C/++, Java, and many other languages, but C# always seems to catch me out. I don't want to use an unsafe code block to do this with pointers, which would be infinitely easier because others who don't know pointers and memory management are going to have to maintain it. Given that bytes[idx] refers to a single byte, not the array it is expecting, is there some kind of cast I can use to get past this?  Is there a better fitted method to use?

I've looked at a dozen sites with sample code, but this multiple string problem never gets shown.  Should I load each string into a separate byte[] and then merge them at the end?

Comment: Neither of language you've mentioned treat byte (`bytes[idx]`) as array of bytes... You may want to edit out unrelated information from the post to avoid discussions about that parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign an array of bytes to a single `byte`.

You need to assign each `byte` separately:

```
var bytes = enc.GetBytes(str);
foreach(var b in bytes)
{
    bytes[idx++] = b;
}
```

After this you don't need to update `idx` with `idx += enc.GetByteCount(str);`

Comment: Be careful of IndexOutOfRangeExceptions if `idx` becomes >= `bytes.Length`

Comment: That's what I thought, but given the sheer amount of data (this is all HL7 HIPAA data for many patients in a major hospital, I was hoping for some kind of bulk encoding.  I hate to kludge something with brute force, but I guess I have to here. Thanks for confirming my worst fears ;).

Comment: I won't blow out the bytes[] range. I will be sending only a single patient over the socket at a time, and I can vastly increase the array size (it's already got 50% fudge factor).  Thanks for the warning though.

Answer (score 1):

[Encoding.GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c20ss51h(v=vs.110).aspx) already does most of the work of copying data to same array for you, the only step needed is to get size of array which is also covered in the same MSDN article:

> To calculate the exact array size required by GetBytes to store the resulting bytes, you should call the GetByteCount method. To calculate the maximum array size, call the GetMaxByteCount method. The GetByteCount method generally allows allocation of less memory, while the GetMaxByteCount method generally executes faster.

Just call `GetByteCount` for each string and than call `GetBytes` with increasing offsets.

Comment: You don't even need the `GetByteCount`. this line will do the trick: `idx+= enc.GetBytes(str,0,str.Length,bytes,idx);`

Answer (score 0):

The heck with it. I decided to do it in C (unsafe code) and just comment it well for those who might follow.